# Unusual error in all ggplot2 commands

Tags: r, ggplot2

I do not even imagine how and why I am receiving all this output from any command in ggplot package, I've tried reinstalling R, packages, but nothings works so far.

```
> library(ggplot2)
> qplot(x=1:10, y=1:10)
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: col, color, pch, cex, lty, lwd, srt, adj, bg, fg, min, max
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: col, color, pch, cex, lty, lwd, srt, adj, bg, fg, min, max
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: col, color, pch, cex, lty, lwd, srt, adj, bg, fg, min, max
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: col, color, pch, cex, lty, lwd, srt, adj, bg, fg, min, max
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: col, color, pch, cex, lty, lwd, srt, adj, bg, fg, min, max
```

Here is my session info.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-0   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.6.0       grid_2.15.2        gtable_0.1.2      
 [6] labeling_0.1       MASS_7.3-22        munsell_0.4        plyr_1.8           proto_0.3-9.2     
[11] RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.2     scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2      tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: Is this from a clean R (`--vanilla`) R session?  Have you tried `install.packages(ggplot2,depend=TRUE)`? I have `grid` v 2.16.0 ... maybe there is some other package mismatch since this is a brand-new version of `ggplot2`?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/CxDzO1HQTaE

Comment: Yes, I'm running vanilla `R` session. I've tried to install dependencies, but it didn't seem to work out. I knew the info in the link you have provided, but it doesn't really answer my question, because neither `ggplot2` and nor `plyr` are in development version in my case.

Comment: OK, I just updated to `plyr` 1.8 (from 1.7.1) and was able to reproduce your problem (Ubuntu 12.04).  Sounds like time for a bug/issues report ...

Comment: I knew that there might be something wrong with version of plyr

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/737

Comment: If you suspected `plyr` why didn't you mention something?  Could have saved me a couple of minutes ...

Comment: Make sure you reinstall `ggplot2` from a clean R session - this error indicates that you haven't correctly updated. (Which is not your fault - R is terrible at given error messages if the installation fails for some reason)

Comment: @hadley: Even re-installation produces the same error again.

Comment: What mirror are you using? May be it doesn't have the right version of ggplot2

Comment: @hadley: I used USA(IA) and USA(CA 1).

Answer (score 7):

Re-instllation of `ggplot2 0.9.3` form `UK (London)` mirror resolved the issue.